# Facing issue in java MultiThreading

Tags: java, multithreading

Im facing one problem in streaming data capture for reading the broadcast data during multithreading, pls help or suggest,

Actually there is one class which is reading data from one of the udp socket. Another class accepts the tcp connection from every client request, creates a thread for every client and request the same udp class for data. The thing is working with 1st thread which gets created. But when i request with another client from another pc/ip the packets get losted to the 2nd client/thread

I have made a workaround by creating a list where im storing the Threads outputstream object
and looping it to send the data to all the client. But this is just temporary as it ll delay the packets if clients/connections gets increased.

code for reading UDP Data

```
   public class EventNotifier    
    {
      private InterestingEvent ie;
      public DatagramSocket clientSocket;
      public String[] split_str;

      byte[] receiveData;

      HashMap<String, String> secMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


      public EventNotifier(InterestingEvent event)
      {
        ie = event; 
     clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(9050);
        receiveData = new byte[500];
      }



      public String getDataFeed(String client_id)
      {
        try 
        {
             DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
             clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
             String s = new String(receivePacket.getData());
             String split_str = s.split(","); 
             if(secMap.containsValue(split_str[0]))
                  return s;
             else
                  return "";
             } catch(Exception e3) {}
      }
     }// end of eventNotifier class
```

code for multithreading handling client requests

```
public class multiServer 
{

    static protected List<PrintWriter> writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
    static String client_id = "";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
       try
       {
           ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(8858);
           Socket incoming;
           while(true)
           {
             incoming = servsock.accept();
             multiServerThread  connection = new multiServerThread(incoming);

             Thread t1 = new Thread(connection);
             t1.start();
           }
       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
            System.out.println("couldnt make socket");
       }
    }
}

class multiServerThread extends Thread implements InterestingEvent
{

    Socket incoming;
    PrintWriter out=null;
    PrintWriter broad=null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String cliString=null;
    private EventNotifier en; 
    int id;

    public static String udp_data;

    public void interestingEvent(String str1)
    {
          this.udp_data = str1;
    }
    public String getUdpData()
    {
      String _udp_data = this.udp_data;
      return _udp_data;
    }
    multiServerThread(Socket incoming)
    {  
        this.incoming=incoming;
        en = new EventNotifier(this);
    } 
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            out = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream()));
        cliString = in.readLine();
        multiServer.writers.add(out);
        while(true)
                {
               try
                   {
                    udp_data = en.getDataFeed(cliString);
                    if(udp_data!=null && udp_data.length()>0)
                    {
              //workaround for serving the data to all cleints who are connected    
                        for (int i=0; i<multiServer.writers.size();i++)
                        {
                            broad=multiServer.writers.get(i);
                            broad.println(udp_data.trim());
                        }
             //else will directly write to the outputstream object for every thread which is connected
             // out.println(udp_data.trim());
                    }

               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                 System.out.println("exception "+e);
               }
               Thread.sleep(1);

            }
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("IO Exception :: "+ e);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.print("exception "+ e);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have static for `public static String udp_data`

Comment: Please edit your post to make it comprehensible, and please run it again after you've fixed the exception-ignoring catch blocks.

Comment: i have declared the udp_data string as static as it should be common across all threads

Comment: updated the code @EJP , pls check !!!

Comment: You still have `} catch(Exception e3) {}` and you still haven't clarified your question. I don't understand this sentence: "Another class accepts the tcp connection from every client request, creates a thread for every client and request the same udp class for data."

Comment: @EJP - Another class accepts TCP connection means , it like one class is continously running in while loop where its accepting TCP/IP connections from one port i.e. 8858 and it creates a thread for every client to read the data from udp port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need mutual exclusion (or a different design).

For example, what will happen if two threads call `multiServer.writers.add(out);`  concurrently?

From the ArrayList Javadocs

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or [...])

Another problem is two calling `udp_data = en.getDataFeed(cliString);` concurrently. The second thread might overwrite the result of the first. You'll loose data!

What happens if one thread calls `for (int i=0; i<multiServer.writers.size();i++)` while another thread is busy doing `multiServer.writers.add(out);`? The size may have increased, before `out` has actually been added to the list!

```
public class multiServer 
{

    private List<PrintWriter> writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();

    public synchronized void addWriter(PrintWrite out) {
         writers.add(out);
    }
    public synchronized void serveAllWriters(String data) {
         for (int i=0; i<multiServer.writers.size();i++)
         {
             broad=multiServer.writers.get(i);
             broad.println(data);
         }
    }
}
```

Now when a thread tries to add a writer, the `synchronized`s will make sure no other thread is `add`ing or printing. So `multiServerThread` should be fixed to use the new methods:

```
class multiServerThread extends Thread implements InterestingEvent
{
      //...
      private String udp_data;
      //...
      myMultiServer.addWriter(out);

      //...
      udp_data = en.getDataFeed(cliString);
      if(udp_data!=null && udp_data.length()>0)
            myMultiServer.serveAllWriters(udp_data.trim());
      //...
}
```

There might be more problems, not sure I don't fully understand your code. The question you must ask yourself is, can another thread read and/or write the same data or object? Yes? Then you'll need proper synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply my problem is like the data which is read on udp port by every thread should be consistent and concurrent across every thread.i understand that there will be a data lost if same variable or method is being overwritted or called thats y i need a solution how to call a method within the thread which ll unqiuely identify every thread and data will be same across all threads

Comment: @praveen2609 That's virtually impossible. You need some synchronization to keep data consistent. I don't see why my answer doesn't meet your requirements. All received udp_data.trim() gets printed to all running threads.

Comment: Im new to this blog, is there any ways to chat with you i may explain u my problem exactly

Comment: As per my understanding what u said is like , i need to make synchronization for the writers.add and to serverallwriters, but in that case every thread will call the same method and will server the data multiple times doesn't it have lost of data packets from udp

Comment: @praveen2609 http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12994/facing-issue-in-java-multithreading

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to initiate the chat r reply to chat

Comment: will explain you over here only

Comment: see i need a multiclient program which will accept connection from client machines on tcp socket which will continously loop though for accepting theconnection from the clients (i.e. new clients) which is happening perfectly

Comment: As per ur suggestion i will create the synchrnoized methods to add the outputstream object to writers list which will get call when the thread is created for the client

Comment: @praveen2609 I want to avoid extended talk in comments, cause it fills up stackoverflow with spam (not interesting for other people). I believe my code does (more or less) what you require. Maybe you can implement it and test it out. If you can say, I tried A and B was hoping to see C but the program did D. It's much easier for me to help you. You can start a new question, with the new code and link back to this question. I'll check your profile so I won't miss it. Good luck!

Comment: now in the run method when i call the udp class for getting the data and pass it to the another synchronized method which ll server the data to all the writers